# Excel: CountIf Cell Starts With Certain Numbers

Tags: excel, formula, countif

I am trying to count up the number of cells that start with a certain number. If the number starts with a 1, it belongs in class A. If it starts with a 2, it belongs in class B, and if it starts with a 4, it belongs in class C. The trouble I am having is when using COUNTIF, it counts it if the number as a whole contains that number rather than start with it.

For example, the numbers would be: 10009045, 29400033, 4006132. The first one belongs in class A, the second is class B, and the third in class C. But COUNTIF is counting all of them as belonging in all 3 classes because it contains the number no matter the position.

I have tried using COUNTIF, and ISNUMBER(SEARCH).

```
{ SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("1*",O3:O19)),1)) } returns the same result as COUNTIF
```

Comment: You're trying to count how many A's and B's and C's you get? Or are you trying to label them based on the value of the first number. Is it always the first number you're doing this for?

Comment: `SUMPRODUCT` and converting the number to a string by be a better option `=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(TEXT(O3:O19,"@"),1)="1"))` (notice the last `1` is in quotes)

Comment: @MarkS. The latter, I'm trying to label them based on the value of the first number, and yes it is always the first number that I am using for this.

Comment: @abbsichel I just added an answer which should do this for you. Lmk if you have any questions in the comments there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you had said you're trying to label the rows based on the value of the first number, this is how I'd approach it.

**1. Make a table with the key.**

This should have 2 columns, the first column having the 1, 2, 3 etc. The second column should have the labels you want: A, B, C etc.

**2. Create another column in the dataset where you will now pull in these labels.**

I'm going to call the table you just made "Table", so highlight the table you just made where I put table. and I'm assuming your numbers are in `A2` down.

`=Vlookup(value(left(A2,1)),Table,2,0)`

What this does is it takes the value of the leftmost number, finds it in the reference table then pulls the second column which has the label and puts that label where the formula is. You can then pivot this and or use a `COUNTIF` or `COUNTIFS` function to figure out how many there are of each.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, but to count the number of cells with a specific number at the start you can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT($A$1:$A$4)="1"))
```

Otherwise, if you want to return the proper group, assuming you have `100009037`in A1:

```
=CHOOSE(LEFT(A1,1),"Group A", "Group B", "Group C")
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

=COUNTIF(range,"1*")

=COUNTIF(range,"2*")

And so on.

Comment: Note, depending on how the data is formatted, this might return `0` even if it starts with `1`, `2`, etc.